# Java version cannot be recognized on java.com

Tags: java

Recently reinstalled system and meet interesting problem. I installed java jdk8, however when I try to verify version on java.com it asks to install java. Meanwhile:

> java - version

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

> echo %JAVA_HOME%

```
E:\Programms\Java\JDK8
```

> echo %JRE_HOME%

```
E:\Programms\Java\JDK8\jre
```

> echo %PATH%

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Wi
    ndows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Pr
    ogramms\Java\JDK8\bin;E:\Programms\Java\JDK8\jre\bin;
```

Java Control Panel > Security > Enable Java content in Browser is checked

Why browser and java.com does not recognize my java instalation? Java plug-in is not included in jdk?

Comment: may be it requires `JAVA_HOME` env variable?

Comment: Which browser and what about your browser settings?

Comment: @Yarh, check JAVA_HOME

Comment: Probably the browser is 32 bits, then indeed there are not going to be any Java plugins installed in it if you installed the 64 bits Java runtime as part of the JDK. I always install the 64 bits JDK and then separately I install the 32 bits runtime through java.com (minding not to install the flipping toolbar).

Comment: @Gimby will 32 jre interfere with 64 jdk?

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı Fierfox and Chrome on windows. I was surprised there is no 64 bit version for windows

Comment: @Yarh not at all. In fact they complete each other as you're now finding out.

Comment: @Gimby I think you should convert your comments into an answer.

Comment: @Gimby you were completly right. Problem occured because browser was 32 bit, while my sdk was 64. Instaling 32 bit sdk alongside with 64 resolved a problem. Please post it as an unswer

Comment: @Yarh alright, as per your request I posted the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comments as an answer as per request by Yarh:

Probably the browser is 32 bits, then indeed there are not going to be any Java plugins installed in it if you installed the 64 bits Java runtime as part of the JDK. I always install the 64 bits JDK and then separately I install the 32 bits runtime through java.com (minding not to install the flipping toolbar).

There is no conflict to install both a 32 bits runtime and a 64 bits runtime, that is the advised way to support all types of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need to install the JRE rather than a JDK using the Windows installer at (java.oracle.com).

This should set up everything properly.